# Setting click handlers dynamically on generated dom by Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Whoever solves this will be the Javascript, Angular Genius...

It's about injecting clickHandlers (function/scope) to the dynamically generated DOM elements

In this basic setup the DOM elements are generated by Angular, Angular is bootstrapped to an element and content is populated by an array. .

Is there a way that we can set click handlers on each anchor dynamically (no need of cross browser implementation, addEventHandler would suffice).

It's best to look at the Fiddle link itself given below to get the full picture.

```
<div id="navigation" data-ng-cloak>
    <ul data-ng-controller="foliosController" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li data-ng-repeat="folio in folios" class="active"><a href="#">{{folio.title}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var self = this;
var navigation = angular.module("navigation", []);
navigation.controller("foliosController", function($scope){self.foliosController($scope)});
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("navigation"), ["navigation"]);
```

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/casadev/n50ecw5m/

Bonus: If there's a way to set only the first anchor as active.

EDIT:
There's a clickHandler defined within the scope, need to link the clickHandler with the generated dom links.

```
clickHandler: function(event) {
    alert(event.target);
}
```

Edit 2: Some progress but attached clickHandlers manually to stay inside the scope, wished if angular could do it. 
http://jsfiddle.net/casadev/n50ecw5m/14/

Mini Question after my own answer:
Is there a way to avoid templateUrl in case I don't need to have one?

Comment: Why don't you just use ng-click?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat my requirement is to stay inside the scope (no code on the html attributes), if you notice there's a clickHandler function defined within the scope, please review the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/casadev/n50ecw5m/

Comment: I've answered my question, can anyone suggest how can I get rid of templateUrl in the config when function if I don't need to specify one. The code doesn't work without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, use Router instead of clickHandlers on the generated content and assign controllers as per the link, routers can let you specify Controllers that I can have defined and called within the scope and call other functions within the scope. No need for ng-click or any sort of manual clickHandlers. I wish if I could not specify a templateUrl since I don't need but it's not working if I omit it, appreciate any comments.

```
<div id="navigation" data-ng-cloak>
<ul id="folios" ng-controller="FoliosController" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li data-ng-repeat="folio in folios" class="" active="true">
        <a href="#/folios/{{folio.productId}}" id="{{folio.productId}}">{{folio.title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

```
puremvc.define(
{
name: "modules.search.view.components.Navigation",

constructor: function() {
    var self = this;
    var navigation = angular.module("navigation", ["ngRoute"]);

    navigation.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){self.config($routeProvider, $locationProvider)});
    navigation.controller("FoliosController", function($scope, $location){self.foliosController($scope, $location)});
    navigation.controller("SearchController", function($scope, $location, $routeParams){self.searchController($scope, $location, $routeParams)});

    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("navigation"), ["navigation"]);
}
},
{
$scope: null,
$location: null,
folios: [],

foliosController: function($scope, $location) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$location = $location;
    this.$scope.folios = this.folios;
},

searchController: function($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams);
},

config: function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when("/", {templateUrl:"js/modules/partials/list.html"}).
    when("/folios/:productId", {templateUrl:"js/modules/partials/search.html", controller:"SearchController"});
},

init: function(folios) {
    for(folio in folios) {
        this.folios.push(folios[folio]);
    }
    this.$scope.$apply();
}
},
{});
```

Answer (score 0):

Who made you use angular and gave you that requirement?  All you need to do is `ng-click="clickHandler($event)"`, or even better `ng-click="clickHandler(folio)"` to pass the data you're interested in.  `ng-repeat` constantly shuffles and creates/destroys elements when the list changes, manually managing those bindings would be a nightmare.  You could use jquery of course and something like `$('ul.nav-pills a`).on('click', clickHandler)`.  Then you would have to put your code in a`$scope.$apply()` to get angular to notice any changes.

Instead of adding another dependency on jquery and creating an annoyance for anyone maintaining your code I would spend my time arguing to your boss that you should use `ng-click`.

Comment: part of the equation is that we have heavily employed multicore of pure mvc's connected via pipes along with a statemachine, angular comes in the play with databinding. I'm aware of calling ng-click passing any function but then we lost the scope of that component, and instead we are in the global scope. Secondly manually managing the data bindings is fully under control, its just populating the array. (behind the scenes is a highly decoupled system). Yes we are aware of jQuery click also, but wanted really really genius dynamic clickHandler injection.